# How do I skip waiting for a timer in UI tests

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I have VueJS SPA and C# Selenium E2E test for this app.

I am writing a test for a scenario where the user needs to wait first 5 minutes, then 10, then 30. While waiting, nothing should happen in the system. How can I skip the timeout so that the tests don't take too long?

I tried using WebDriverWait but that's not what I need because the test stops and it takes a lot of time.

What I need is like "jump into the future" in the test.

The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
sut.OpenSampleClientHomePage();
sut.ClickLoginButton();

sut.SkipMinutes(5); // what needs to be implemented 

sut.EnterPassword(SomePassword);
```

Comment: Inject the timer into your code and then mock it in your tests

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int)` not work for your purposes?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I tried WebDriverWait but it's not what I need. Unfortunately Thread.Sleep(int) works the same way and the test just pauses and I still have to wait some amount of time

Comment: If the System Under Test uses something like `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.UtcNow` (or any other DateTime static method), then you cannot simply "jump into the future." The SUT relies on the system clock. An end-to-end test in Selenium might not be the best solution for this kind of test. Perhaps a manual test that is run as needed would be better. Hopefully the logic for this timeout does not use static DateTime members so you can do what @Flydog57 mentioned, but that would be for a unit test, not a Selenium test.